# SSD with trim support - do I have to configure anything?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, trim

If I install Windows 7 on SSD drive with TRIM support or if I add new SSD drive with TRIM support to existing Windows 7 installation do I have to configure anything to actually use the TRIM or is it some automatic background operation? If it helps I'm using OCZ Vertex 2.

Comment: My one word answer:
NO.

A longer answer:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/e7/archive/2009/05/05/support-and-q-a-for-solid-state-drives-and.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're running at least firmware 1.4, TRIM is native on the drive so no configuration is needed from you

Answer (score 2):

Observe that only Microsoft's own storage drivers and Intel's storage drivers support passing along TRIM commands to the drive. So depending on your platform you need to take care as to which drivers you install in order to make sure you have TRIM. Beyond that there is nothing you need to do to get TRIM working. Windows 7 takes care of the rest.